# Rails forms, params and object methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, partial, parameters

I have form with such code:

```
= form_for @offer, url: some_url_path do |offer|
  = render partial: 'form', locals: { offer: offer }
```

withing that `form` partial I render other partial

```
= render 'prices_table', offer: offer
```

Contents of `prices_table` partial looks like this:

```
%tr
  %td= check_box_tag(:outer_price_toggler, 1, params[:outer_price_toggler].present?, class: "price-toggler")
  %td Aussenkabine
  %td
    .form-group.price-form-group
      = offer.text_field :outer_price, class: "form-control actual-price"
  %td
    .form-group.price-form-group
      = offer.text_field :outer_price_normal, class: "form-control normal-price"
```

The purpose of `:outer_price_toggler` checkbox is to activate other two fields, but toggler is not a part of the object. Here `params[:outer_price_toggler].present?` is used to understand, whether user has selected this checkbox and both other fields should be enabled for the user. For adding new offer this works perfectly, but it does not work for editing, because originally I do not have any `params[:outer_price_toggler]` stored anywhere.

Questions:

1) can I somehow add this `:outer_price_toggler` to params on edit page? That is to modify original `params`.

2) can I get current value of `:outer_price` and `:outer_price_normal` in order to find out whether this toggler should be activated? So, can I use something like `offer.outer_price.present? || offer.outer_price_normal.present?` instead of `params[:outer_price_toggler].present?`?

If I use something like this, I get `undefined method 'inner_price' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x000000082b3bf0>` error, but, maybe, there is some other similar way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could also pass in `@offer` object as local all the way to the `prices_table` partial, you can do

```
%tr
  %td= check_box_tag(:outer_price_toggler, 1, offer_object.outer_price.persent? || offer_object.outer_price_normal.present?, class: "price-toggler")
```

Comment: Yes, this actually works perfectly. If version with `offer.object.method` (it looks cleaner) will not work - this will be best answer for sure :)